# Subtracting one big amount from few smaller

Tags: php, arrays, subtraction

I have an array:

```
array(
key1  => 2,
key2 => 5,
key3 => 10,
keyn => n.
)
```

I'm trying to subtract from it 12 and accordingly decrease the values and update the array:

```
key1  => 0 (2 - 12 is -10, so I leave 0)
key2 => 0 (10 left from the first subtraction, so I subtract 10 from the second value, as the result is -5, I leave 0)
key3 => 5 (5 left from the above subtraction so I subtract 5 from 10)
keyn => n (other values not affected by the subtraction should remain unchanged).
```

I got stuck with it. I would appreciate any tips how could I solve the problem.

Comment: The question is unclear. Can you edit it with a much clearer explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```php
$input = array(
    "key1"  => 2,
    "key2" => 5,
    "key3" => 10,
);

$rest = 12;
foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
    $newValue = $value - $rest;
    $rest = 0;
    if ($newValue < 0) {
        $rest = $newValue *= -1;
        $newValue = 0;
    }
    $output[$key] = $newValue;
}

var_dump($output);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["key1"]=>
  int(0)
  ["key2"]=>
  int(0)
  ["key3"]=>
  int(5)
}
```

Comment: It works as long as there are exactly 3 elements in the array. If I add key4 it is also decreased by 3 (as key3) and it should remain unchanged.

Comment: I updated it already - set $rest to 0 in the loop, try it.

Comment: Gerat. It works as I wanted. Thank you!